# Where is the cast here? LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a number of entity framework tables that I have made support an interface `IHistoricEntity` using their parital classes. `IHistoricEntity` has `ActiveTo` `Datetime?` property.

```
// Auto generated LINQ to Entities domain service:
[EnableClientAccess()]
public partial class ProductService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<ProductDBEntities>
{
    public IQueryable<ANALYSIS_CODES> GetANALYSIS_CODES()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.ANALYSIS_CODES;
    }
 ...
}

// My Partial class to add interface
public partial class ANALYSIS_CODES : IHistoricEntity
{}
```

I am trying to refactor this working code to a method:

```
List<ANALYSIS_CODE> filtered = (from rec in ps.GetANALYSIS_CODES() where rec.ActiveTo == null select rec).ToList()
```

Like so:

```
private List<T> Filter<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable) where T : IHistoricEntity
{
    return (from rec in queryable where rec.ActiveTo == null select rec).ToList();
}

// called like this:
List<ANALYSIS_CODE> filtered = Filter(ps.GetANALYSIS_CODES());
```

This gives this exception on the `ToList`:

> Unable to cast the type 'ANALYSIS_CODES' to type 'IHistoricEntity'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

But where have I asked it to cast to an `IHistoricEntity`? I have mearly said that `T` must support `IHistoricEntity`.

Comment: Have you tried storing the query in a variable and examining the expression property of it in the debugger before ToListing it? That should show you where the cast is.

Comment: There's nothing useful in there, and when I try to expand results I get the exception.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly accessing the .expression property?  It isn't always visible in the debugger, but you should be able to type it manually.  Also, try query.ToString() in the debugger as that might give a clue too (works for Linq to SQL, don't think I've tried it with Entities yet)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`rec.ActiveTo` refers to a property defined in your interface. Therefore Linq needs to cast `rec` to `IHistoricEntity` before being able to access that property.

Don't be fooled by the exception being raised in `.ToList()`: the Linq query is only evaluated and executed when the records are needed, in this case, when the collection is to be transformed into a `List<>`.

**Update**: I verified @hvd's comment, and indeed, adding a `where T: class` clause changes the Linq expression from

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyType]
    .Where(x => (Convert(x).ActiveTo == Convert(null)))
```

to

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyType]
    .Where(x => (x.ActiveTo == Convert(null)))
```

Comment: "Therefore Linq needs to cast `rec` to `IHistoricEntity` before being able to access that property." -- Almost, but not quite. That requirement is avoided by including a `class` constraint on the generic argument. When the type is known in advance to be a reference type, the conversion to `IHistoricEntity` is a no-op and won't be included. (The cast is otherwise potentially a boxing operation, because `T` could be a struct.)

Comment: @hvd Nice, thanks to both of you, `where T : class, IHistoricEntity` did the trick. And that makes perfect sense to boot!

Comment: Wow! I was founding solution for days! And where T: class fixes it! Thanks a lot!!!1